# Visual C++ Build Tools 2015 inside containers and custom directory

Tags: visual-studio, docker, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

Did anyone manage to:

- install Visual C++ Build Tools 2015
- inside Windows container
- and in a **custom directory**?

Whatever I do, it always installs to standard location: **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0**

Below is the example Dockerfile to demonstrate that it silently ignores `/CustomInstallPath` parameter:

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore:ltsc2016

# download installer
ADD https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126 visualcppbuildtools_full.exe

# install
RUN cmd /c visualcppbuildtools_full.exe /Passive /CustomInstallPath C:\BuildTools

# test
RUN dir C:\BuildTools
```

I've tried with `microsoft/nanoserver` base images too, can't install at all.

I've tried [installing via Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/vcbuildtools) which also allows passing `/CustomInstallPath`, same result.

There are some discussions where people recommend fully **uninstalling** VS and anything related, but here I'm using a completely standard image, so it shouldn't matter. Anyway I've tried calling `/uninstall` first - didn't help.

Comment: Hi, did you run the docker build on windows 10 or windows server 2016? I am trying to install visual studio 2015 build tools in standard location inside windows container , I always get system cannot find path specified. I have installed docker on windows 2016 server.

Comment: Might be useful. In the comment (Dockefile) it is mentioned to use a specific tagged image.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/advanced-build-tools-container?view=vs-2017                                                                 `RUN C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache --installPath C:\BuildTools \`

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK some components of the BuildTools "package" will always go in `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` no matter what (i.e. the C++ compiler).